# SQL Error with CASE WHEN Error on From when using GETDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is giving me an error. The error is below. Please help.

The Created Date field is NVARCHAR type.  Everything in the dbo.UNIQUE_PARTS_LIST table is NVARCHAR

> 14 The data types datetime and date are incompatible in the subtract operator.

```
DECLARE @LookBack60 as FLOAT
Set @LookBack60= -60


select distinct part.Part_Num, part.[Part Description], part.[Part Type],

CASE
    WHEN
        (cast(Part.[Created Date] as date) <= DATEADD(MONTH,@LookBack60,GETDATE()))
    THEN 'Not Needed'
    ELSE 
        (getdate() - cast(Part.[Created Date] as date))
    END as 'Intermediate',

CASE
    WHEN
        (cast(Part.[Created Date] as date) <= DATEADD(MONTH,@LookBack60,GETDATE()))
    THEN 'Not Needed'
    ELSE 
        (getdate() - cast(Part.[Created Date] as date)) / (365/12)
    END as 'FINAL',

from dbo.UNIQUE_PARTS_LIST part
WHERE part.[Part Type] = 'Consumable'
order by part.Part_Num asc
```

Comment: I suggest you to add your software in tags such as [tag:sql-server] or [tag:mysql]

Comment: `NVarChar` defaults (in DDL) to a length of `1`. Are you sure that's the length of all of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I changed it to DATEDIFF.